# possible to recreate android keystore

Tags: android, keystore, encryption, keytool

There is no backup of the android keystore used on an app in the play store, but there is a backup of the passwords

is it possible to recreate a valid keystore somehow? perhaps by decrypting an apk

I also don't know the "First name" "Last name" and "Organization" of the keystore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot recreate a keystore and there is no way to upload an update that has been signed with a different keystore.  I ran into this problem a few years ago and I know other devs who have as well.  There is simply no good way to fix it.  I learned to keep several copies of my keystore in several different locations incase anything every happened again!

Comment: okay, I'll just run recovery. there is a backup of the partition but I still need to boot that machine